# Sackur-Tetrode eqation becomes negative

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

The Sackur-Tetrode equation, tells us the entropy of of an ideal microcanonical gas.
It looks like this:

> $S(E,V,N) = kN\text{ln}(\frac{V}{N}(\frac{E}{N})^{3/2})+ kN\cdot c(m)$

Now let's fix the mean energy per particle $E/N = \overline{E}$ and let $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Then $S = kN(c(m)-\text{ln}(\frac{N}{V}\cdot\overline{E}^{(-3/2)})) \rightarrow -\infty$.

How can i make sense of this?

Comment: That is extremely well-known. It is just that this is an expression for the classical ideal gas, and is thus too poor an approximation to work when things are too cold and so forth. Also, if you are not fixing $V/N$, of course it will give nonsensical results.